# elements of list getting deleted in the subsequent iteration of for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to get the cartesian product of two sets given the range of elements and number of sets

```
temp = []
l = []
def loop(x,y):
    global temp
    global l
    if y >0:
        for i in range(x):
            temp.append(i)
            loop(x,y-1)
            if y == 1:
              l.append(temp)
            temp.remove(i)
            
loop(6,3)
print(l)
```

but the output i get for "l" is just a list containing empty list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JUR8.png)

[I tried checking whether the temp list works properly by printing it before appending it into "l" and it works fine ge description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhCc7.png)

[printing "l" after appending temp into "l"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLxNS.png)

Comment: Every time you append `temp` you're appending a reference to the same list. You need to make a copy of it.

Comment: `l.append(temp.copy())`